# How to protect or add authentication over a Lambda Function returning HTML Page

Tags: javascript, rest, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have an application using A REST API Gateway in AWS. That API has a few resources, two of them are as follows

1. **{{API_URL}}/{{API_STAGE}}/show-data** (GET Method) - This endpoint triggers a lambda function that returns an index.html containing jQuery Datatable which then calls the **get-data** endpoint through POST Method using AJAX.
2. **{{API_URL}}/{{API_STAGE}}/get-data** (POST Method) - This endpoint triggers a lambda, gets some information from S3 bucket and then sends the JSON response.

**A brief about my implementation.**

[Following this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-flow) I created a Token Based Lambda Authorizer and added it to **get-data** endpoint in the REST API. This restricts anyone who doesn't have the Bearer Token to access this endpoint. Therefore making it private.

Next in **show-data** endpoint using AJAX I am calling the **get-data** endpoint. When this request is made, anyone can inspect the page, go to the Networks Tab and see all the Request Headers which also includes the sent Token in Authorization Header. Not just that, if anyone checks the source of the page, they will be able to see the code/token added as a header in Ajax Configuration.

So I am stuck trying to make the **show-data** endpoint secure.

**Code of Lambda Function Triggered through show-data**

***index.js***

```
const fs = require('fs');
const html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', { encoding:'utf8' });

const generateHTMLTable = async () => {
    
    const table = `<table id="reportTable" class="display"><thead><tr>{thead}</tr></thead><tbody>{tbody}</tbody><tfoot>{tfoot}</tfoot></table>`;
    const thead = `<th>S.No</th><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Date</th>`;
    let tbody = "";

    return table.replace("{thead}", thead).replace("{tbody}", tbody).replace("{tfoot}", thead);
}

module.exports.showData = async () => {
    const reportTable = await generateHTMLTable();
    
    const modifiedHTML = html.replace("{table}", reportTable);
    
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        },
        body: modifiedHTML
    }
}
```

***index.html (ajax code)***

```
var table = $('#reportTable').DataTable(
  {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    serverMethod: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
      ajax: {
        url: 'get-data',
        dataSrc: 'data',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: function(d){
          return JSON.stringify(d);
        },
        headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "text/json; charset=utf-8",
        // Here is the Authorization Token Passed which can be seen if someone sees the source.
        "Authorization":"Bearer **********************",
        }
      },
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      select: true,
  }
);
```

[image: Image Showing Exposed Bearer Token During API Call to get-data]

**Problem in Hand**

How do I make the **show-data** lambda secure?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to protect a Lambda Function that Renders HTML, we can take the following steps.

1. Create a Cloud Front Distribution with Caching based on Project Requirement. I disabled Caching in the initial phase, since I had to also check for development changes.
2. Create a Lambda function in us-east-1 (N.Virginia) Region and add a trigger of CloudFront and specify the Distribution that you created in Step 1. Set it to execute on Viewer's Request. This lambda will now execute everytime a user goes to the any endpoint/resource created in the REST API. So this can be used as an authorizer which will ask for a username and password.

[The above steps are better explained](https://austinlasseter.medium.com/build-a-password-protected-website-using-aws-lambda-and-cloudfront-3743cc4d09b6/), just change the Origin Path from S3 to the URL which is triggering the lambda, in my case, API Gateway.